# Does reinstalling ubuntu eliminates all existing rootkits/ malware/spyware/ virus etc?

Tags: linux, rootkits, reinstall

If I do a fresh installation of ubuntu from an uninfected cd, will it remove all the existing rootkits/malwares/spywares/viruses etc if any ? Is formatting the hard disk required before reinstalling or these malicious programs will be removed even if the disk is not formatted before reinstalling?

Answer (score 2):

You are required to format the disk completely. There are rumours and even proof of concepts of rootkits hiding in the BIOS, but I haven't seen them in the wild yet.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there any BIOS rootkits for Linux?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner - Just a question that do BIOS rootkits depend on the Operating System which is running as well?

Comment: Slides presented at the Black Hat 2006 describing a BIOS Rootkit can be found [here](http://blackhat.com/presentations/bh-federal-06/BH-Fed-06-Heasman.pdf). The authors developed a proof of concept BIOS rootkit that acts as a Windows NT or as a Linux backdoor.

Comment: Switching *power off* before booting from CD is not very time expensive! (And could maybe prevent *warm-boot* issues)

Comment: so u r saying formatting the hdd and reinstallling ubuntu will get rid of malicious programs ?